# What is the notation of Unit Dual Quaternion Group

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups

The dual quaternion $\mathbb{D}$ is a ring as I know, but the unit dual quaternion is a Lie Group. I cannot find a proper group notation as Sp(1)/SU(2)/$\mathbb{S}^3$ for quaternion. Can anybody give some help?